# Laravel user::create missing data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've used a migration to update my users table to include a username filed, but on signup the field isn't populated in the database:

```
    $input = Input::only(['name', 'username', 'email', 'password']);
    $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
    User::create($input);
    return Redirect::to('login');
```

A dump of the post provides this:

```
array (size=4)
  'name' => string 'Joe Bloggs' (length=13)
  'username' => string 'jbloggs' (length=12)
  'email' => string 'jbloggs@gmail.com' (length=24)
  'password' => string '$2y$10$whgTTwa5g.du/WJfJGhGtO******SYTerzL4bhOuedW4C' (length=60)
```

However the username field is always blank. No errors or warnings. I've tried a rollback and re-migrating, but there is no change.

Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have `username` in your `fillable` array?

Comment: @lukasgeiter Life saver! I've spent about 2 hours on this! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All attributes you pass to `create` need to be defined in the `$fillable` array so you can use them for [mass assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)

In your case:

```
protected $fillable = array('name', 'username', 'email', 'password');
```

Alternatively you could also define the opposite, a set of `guarded` attributes:

```
protected $guarded = array('foo', 'bar');
```

Answer (score 1):

When you add a user in *`eloquent model`* you have an array `$fillable` which allows you to **mass assign** more can be found http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment